# Unpack a C struct on browser?

Tags: javascript, struct, binary, client, binary-data

## EDIT

I found this:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays

Basically if I have something like this:

```
struct someStruct {
  unsigned long id;
  char username[16];
  float amountDue;
};
```

on client side I can do:

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://URI");
ws.binaryType = "arraybuffer";

ws.onmessage = function (e) {
    var buffer = e.data;
    var data_view = new DataView(buffer);
    
    // ... read the data into the buffer ...
    
    var idView = data_view.getUint32(0);
    var usernameView = data_view.getUint32(4);
    var amountDueView = data_view.getFloat32(20);
};
```

The problem is that I want to convert them to normal Javascript objects (numbers, strings etc).

## Original question

I would send data via websocket packed using a C struct, and unpack on browser using Javascript.

I know modules exists for node.js, but I can't find nothing client-side.

Comment: You need two things: First, a serialization format. Second, code to convert to and from that serialization format for each platform you care about. You can use text, XML, JSON, some kind of binary, or whatever makes sense for your use case. JSON is probably a good choice in most cases.

Comment: No JSON, I want a binary format.

Comment: Are the client and server on the same physical machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after some researching, I finally decided this could not be a good idea:

https://justin.harmonize.fm/development/2013/04/28/a-slower-js-msgpack.html

Shortly: javascript is slow in decoding.

Probably it's just more simple to use JSON and `Content-Encoding: gzip`, if it does not slow down your web app.

Answer (score 1):

If you're familiar with [Python struct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html), then you may like [structjs](https://github.com/lyngklip/structjs). It's my attempt at porting Python struct to javascript. As it is, it's for Node, but a client port should be easy.

You won't have issues with alignment or padding (you can specify those explicitly though) for that structure, but you may need to indicate little-endian (by the '<' in the format string) if that's your flavour. You might do like so (I haven't tested this example in any way):

```
let struct = require("./struct") // Node specific, you need to wrap it.
let someStruct = struct('<I16sf') // This is your struct definition
let ws = new WebSocket("ws://URI");
ws.binaryType = "arraybuffer";

ws.onmessage = e => {
    // Unpack using the structure definition. Unpack takes an ArrayBuffer.
    let [id, username, amountDue] = someStruct.unpack(e.data);
    // Use data...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok,
https://www.npmjs.com/package/c-struct looks like what you want. 
Good luck!

Comment: you need to give a brief summary of what the given link is explaining, links can go dead easily.